# grunt-dox generating html file with only title

Tags: gruntjs, jsdoc, docco

I'm using the [grunt-dox grunt plugin](https://github.com/punkave/grunt-dox) to generate [docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) documentation out of a JavaScript file that has [JsDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/) dockblocks.

When I run the grunt task all I get is an HTML file with just the title I specified.  No errors installing grunt-dox or running the task.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.3 but I have a strong feeling thats not why its not working.

Here's some related files for reference:

- [Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/jewelsjacobs/5731635)
- [project.json dependancies](https://gist.github.com/jewelsjacobs/5731625)
- [index.html generated by dox](https://gist.github.com/jewelsjacobs/5731348) - please disregard the formatting with extra spaces
- [JavaScript file I'm trying to document](https://gist.github.com/jewelsjacobs/5730736)

Am I doing something wrong?  Has anyone gotten this to work? BTW I'm running `grunt test` which has the dox task in it.

Help would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this for two days and ready to give up.

UPDATE:  I tried to just run `dox --title POC public/javascripts/build/docs/docs.js  > public/docs/index.html` and it hangs forever.

Grrr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as an answer even though I never found out why this wasn't working.

In case someone else has unsuccessfully gone down this path, I highly suggest taking a look at [what I eventually had to do to get decent API documentation for my javascript / node.js app](http://html5devgal.com/blog/2013/06/10/finally-got-jsdocs-working-with-node-app/)

Basically I went with [node-jsdoc-toolkit](https://github.com/p120ph37/node-jsdoc-toolkit), a shell script and [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell).

Hope this helps someone!